# VisioをC#でInteropでOpenすると、カーソルが奪われる

Tags: c#, visio

C#でVisioのファイル内のShapeを解読するプログラムを書いています。
下記のように複数のファイルを順にOpenし、処理をしているのですが、Open時にユーザーのマウスカーソルを奪っていまいます。

```
Visio.Application app = new Visio.Application() { Visible = false, AlertResponse = 1 };

foreach (var file in files)
{
  doc = app.Documents.Open(file);
  //なにかの処理
}
```

対策として以下のことを試してみましたが、効果はありませんでした。

- appのVisibleをfalseにする。
- Task.Run()で別のスレッドで処理をする
- Openではなく、OpenExを使って読み取り専用でファイルを開く

他に何か方法はありますか?

Comment: そもそも「カーソルが奪われる」とはどのような現象でしょうか？

Comment: @sayuriさん 例えば上記のコードでいうとforeachで繰り返し処理をしている間、ユーザーがExcelを操作していると、セル選択のカーソルが外れます。セルの中に文字を入力中にExcelが非アクティブになります。